# Send Openssl client hello with compression enabled

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl, compression

For testing purposes, I need to simulate a SSL request with compression enabled. I successfully compiled the openssl libraries on my Ubuntu test machine without the no_comp option.

However, when I send the openssl request using -comp option, I see that the compression is set to NONE.

I checked the client hello using wireshark packet capture. I see that compression methods is set to NULL by the client.

How to set the compression method to, say "DEFLATE" ? Looking for some examples.

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1-dev  xx XXX xxxx

openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.1.1-dev  xx XXX xxxx
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: linux-x86_64
compiler: gcc -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPADLOCK_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/compssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1\""  -Wa,--noexecstack
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/compssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific

Server:
sudo openssl s_server -key 384private-key.pem -cert 384server.pem -accept 443 -www -cipher ALL:COMPLEMENTOFALL -comp

Client:
sudo openssl s_client -connect 10.92.0.10:443 -cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA -comp
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
   i:C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd

issuer=C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: ECDSA
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1050 bytes and written 272 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate
---
New, TLSv1.0, Cipher is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Server public key is 384 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 56A50DE80262675795C00BFAFE1A63B6487A83FFE0A7D3AD691C2086E63124DC
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: A3D769131534FAFAB0E5DE59FE9B332911F3C1F28D7668C9AF14078E412AEEF0B04DAB969EDCEC1D1CA963AC58097630
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 39 47 ea b2 1a 38 54 09-56 a7 76 d0 21 81 d2 6a   9G...8T.V.v.!..j
    0010 - 6e d9 b2 10 2f 02 ff 6f-d9 0e 23 4b 3a 7e 84 01   n.../..o..#K:~..
    0020 - f8 86 80 fb ef b1 dc bf-f7 ba 62 c7 e8 eb 48 da   ..........b...H.
    0030 - 6e 03 c2 2d 07 51 e9 b3-df 63 a6 27 06 78 e7 79   n..-.Q...c.'.x.y
    0040 - 20 b4 32 a9 6d 8a ab b8-f2 59 c5 f7 76 25 b9 e7    .2.m....Y..v%..
    0050 - 5e 99 66 4f 45 d1 b1 2b-df f4 0b 7e 70 f7 93 b3   ^.fOE..+...~p...
    0060 - 92 98 51 ee ac d4 ce 68-a0 95 fa de c5 e9 f2 d6   ..Q....h........
    0070 - ed 37 93 e3 64 05 91 1a-32 e9 f2 19 d3 43 98 31   .7..d...2....C.1
    0080 - 72 48 89 0c 37 53 67 1b-b6 09 f9 ce 22 20 9f de   rH..7Sg....." ..
    0090 - a2 12 68 db 8c 44 f9 5b-de a2 fd 39 cd fc e2 1f   ..h..D.[...9....
    00a0 - 30 c0 1a 87 42 25 86 e0-c4 44 9b 53 ee a9 f3 90   0...B%...D.S....

    Start Time: 1508783166
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
    Extended master secret: yes
```

Comment: Works for me. Please add the output of `openssl version -a` to your question so that the compile options can be seen

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Updated the question with output of openssl version -a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your output of `openssl version -a`

> compiler: gcc -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H ...

What is missing here is `-DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED`. This means you did not add the necessary configure options to add zlib. The default is to not add zlib and without zlib no compression is supported. To add zlib support use either `zlib` or `zlib-dynamic`, i.e.:

```
./Configure ... zlib-dynamic --prefix= ...
```

Comment: Adding the zlib-dynamic option worked. Thank you! Able to send client hello with DEFLATE as compression method.